# Writing to file geodatabase in R on Windows?

Tags: gdal, r, file-geodatabase

The title above basically states the question. I have looked around but haven't quite found anything yet. I see this driver:

https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html

I haven't seen any R implementation of it yet. I see that one has to add this plugin to GDAL: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FileGDB

Undoubtedly I'm not the first person to want to do this. Is anyone aware of any attempts to implement this in R?

Comment: Have you seen `arcgisbindings`?: https://esricanada-ce.github.io/r-arcgis-tutorials/3-R-ArcGIS-Scripting.pdf

Comment: This seems promising!